# Problem making an object iterable using an arrow function

Tags: javascript, class, object, arrow-functions, iterable

I am learning JavaScript, I created a class and now I need to make it iterable.
The class `Group` is a `Set` of values with methods to add, remove and check the elements of the set.

The part of creating the class was a previous exercise of my textbook, I saw the solution for that part and I tested it, it is correct for sure. My problem is from`[Symbol.iterator]` on.
Here is the code

```js
class Group {

    constructor() {

        this.theGroup = [];
    }

    add( element ) {

        if( !this.has(element) ) this.theGroup.push(element);
    }

    remove( element ) {

        this.theGroup = this.theGroup.filter( x => x != element );
    }

    has( element ) {

        return this.theGroup.includes(element);
    }

    static from( elements ) {

        let group = new Group;

        for( const x of elements ) {

            group.add(x);
        }

        return group;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {

        let i = 0;

        return next = () => {

            if( i >= this.theGroup.length ) return { done : true };

            else return { value : this.theGroup[i++], done : false };
        };
    }
    
}

// the following is here only to show that the code before [Symbol.iterator] works

const group = Group.from([10, 20]);

console.log(group.has(10));
group.add(10);
group.remove(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
group.remove(10);
console.log(group.has(20));

// end of demostration

for (let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

I get the error

```
return next = () => {
       ^
ReferenceError: next is not defined
```

And if I make the arrow function anonymous: `return () => { ...code continues` then I got this other error

```
for (let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I am using an arrow function to avoid changing `this`.

Someone knows what's going on?
How can I make the class iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return an object with a key of next,.

eg.. `{ next: () => {}}`  not `return next = () => {}`

Fixed example below..

```js
class Group {

    constructor() {

        this.theGroup = [];
    }

    add( element ) {

        if( !this.has(element) ) this.theGroup.push(element);
    }

    remove( element ) {

        this.theGroup = this.theGroup.filter( x => x != element );
    }

    has( element ) {

        return this.theGroup.includes(element);
    }

    static from( elements ) {

        let group = new Group;

        for( const x of elements ) {

            group.add(x);
        }

        return group;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {

        let i = 0;

        return {next: () => {

            if( i >= this.theGroup.length ) return { done : true };

            else return { value : this.theGroup[i++], done : false };
        }};
    }
    
}

// the following is here only to show that the code before [Symbol.iterator] works

const group = Group.from([10, 20]);

console.log(group.has(10));
group.add(10);
group.remove(10);
console.log(group.has(10));
group.remove(10);
console.log(group.has(20));

// end of demostration

for (let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Wow I wasn't expecting to fix the issue with a couple of brakets! Thank you, those iterators are becoming more clear.